# proof compactness of sets

Tags: compactness

Let $$K ⊂ R^m$$ and $$L ⊂ R^n$$ be compact subsets.

Show:

a) The set $$ K × L: = \{(x, y): x ∈ K, y ∈ L\} ⊂ R^{m+n}$$ is also compact.

I have to show that this is bounded and closed. 
But how do I do that?

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Bounded should not be a problem in either case. Have you tried proving that either $K\times L$ or $K+L$ is closed? What would the structure of such a proof look like?

Comment: I don't know, can you help me?